# vue.js build error for production (can't understand index.html)

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I uploaded my project to the server. I did: `npm run build`. It finished successfully. When I try to go to the website, It shows the following thing:

```
<% for (var chunk of webpack.chunks) { for (var file of chunk.files) { if (file.match(/\.(js|css)$/)) { %> <% }}} %>
<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.serviceWorkerLoader %>
```

I am using Webpack.

What's wrong?